# Where to find Apple's new command-line delivery tool Transporter?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, metadata, app-store-connect

I received the following email from Apple:

> You can now deliver your app's In-App Purchase and Game Center metadata to the App
>       Store using Transporter, Apple’s command-line delivery tool. To deliver with
>       Transporter, you must use App Store packages, which are directories that contain your 
>       app's In-App Purchase and Game Center metadata and assets.
>
> You can also use Transporter to look up your existing app's metadata to retrieve
>       the data in the correct XML format. This can help you to familiarize yourself with
>       the  XML format, and make it easier to update your In-App Purchases and Game Center
>       metadata.
>
> To learn more about App Store packages, including how to create them, see the App
>       Metadata Specification document available for download from the Manage Your
>       Applications module on iTunes Connect.
>
> For additional information on downloading and installing Transporter, see the
>       Transporter User Guide available for download from the Manage Your Applications
>       module   on iTunes Connect.

I would like to take a look at our metadata as XML, but I could not find any link to download the tool whether in iTunes Connect or in developer centre. Where is this tool?

Comment: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/transporter/1.7.6/iTMSTransporter_1.7.6.pkg.gz

Comment: Transporter 2.0 is available here: https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/en.lproj/static.html#apdAe41970bd

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following is stated in the "Transporter Quick Start Guide" available on iTunes Connect:

> ### Installing Transporter
>
> You must download and install Transporter if it
> does not exist on your system.
>
> If you have Xcode or Application Loader
> installed, look for Transporter within the app itself:
>
> #### Xcode
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application
> Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/ bin
>
> #### Application Loader
>
> /Developer/Applications/Utilities/Application
> Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin
>
> Click [this link to download Transporter](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/transporter/1.7.6/iTMSTransporter_1.7.6.pkg.gz) if you do not have it installed. Unzip, double-click the installation package (iTMSTransporter_1.7.6.pkg), and follow the instructions that appear.

Comment: i intalled the package but when i call iTMSTransporter it returns me -bash: cd: iTMSTransporter: Not a directory

Comment: You run executables in the current directory as "./filename", so you'd use "./iTMSTransporter [params]"

Comment: Do you know if iTMSTransporter lets you edit your description for an existing app?

Comment: Looks like it's moved to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter` (no `MacOS` anymore).

Comment: zip is not extracting to .pkg?

Comment: @idurvesh Looks like there is an issue with the download. Archive Utility is just creating a .cpgz from the .gz file for me. Try a third party tool like [The Unarchiver](https://theunarchiver.com/) and it seems to extract properly.

Comment: Thanks also found another solution, you can just remove the .gz and it will auto make it .pkg.