# iTunes Connect Batch upload screenshots for multiple languages

Tags: app-store-connect

I have an update to my app and I have to upload new screenshots. This takes a long time for just one language, but I have 8 languages and it requires me to manually upload the new screenshots for each.

Is there any way to batch this? Any utility out there?

Comment: ***Transporter*** is now available. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191678/where-to-find-apples-new-command-line-delivery-tool-transporter

Answer (score 6):

Checkout deliver (http://github.com/krausefx/deliver), which lets you upload screenshots for all devices in different languages from the command line.

It uses the `itmstransporter` under the hood: https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver/blob/master/lib/deliver/itunes_transporter.rb

Answer (score 3):

Would like to know about such batch uploader too!

My ways for speeding up the upload:

1. open the pages with different languages in several tabs or browsers and uploading them in parallel (may be it is better to create several copies of folders with screenshots, so that every tab will turn to its own folder, because it seems like uploading blocks the folder
2. if you are uploading the same! screenshots to the different languages, you'd better upload them for one language, and then use the "Activate new language" procedure. In this case your previously uploaded screenshots from the default localization will be copied.