# is there iTunes Connect Game Center REST API?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there a way to connect iTunes Connect in order to manage the Game center.
Specifically, I want add 500 different leader boards for my game which has different 500 maps. And this number can increase. Therefore, I want to add these leader boards dynamically from an outside server which I will program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a command line tool (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191678/where-to-find-apples-new-command-line-delivery-tool-transporter) for details) that can upload them. You could maybe run that on your server?